# UIImageView From Left to Right Animation on View

Tags: xcode, animation, uiimage

How can I call `UIImageView` animation from left to right scrolling.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Please edit your question to clarify what you are looking for!**  If you are really talking about animation please clarify which kind of animation you want.

But I suppose you are talking about the `UIScrollView` `paging mode` where you use horizontal scrolling with images. It is something you can see for e.g. in the pictures app.

What you need is a scroll view wich has the paging mode property set to yes.

There is a need Apple [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) on doing that. It will demonstrate you best on how to accomplish something like horizontal scrolling.